# How to make join operations in dplyr silent?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr (version 0.4.1) prints the colnames by which it is performing the join. Is it possible to turn this option off?

R code:

```
library(dplyr)
a=data.frame(x=1,y=2)
b=data.frame(x=1,z=10)
aa=inner_join(a,b)
```

for the last line, dplyr prints:

```
Joining by: "x"
```

that is nice for interactive work, but I am running in Rscript and all these lines are clogging my screen.

Comment: If you add `by`, you would not see the message, I think. `aa=inner_join(a,b, by = "x")`

Comment: *A message lists the variables so that you can check they're right - to suppress the message, supply a character vector.* It's right there in the `join` help file at the `by` argument description

Comment: I often join data within a function, not knowing which variables will end up matching, so the suppressMessages solution works well for me.

Comment: Landed here because I was using the parameter "on" (coming from [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)) instead of "by" as it should be in [dplyr::left_join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html). Dplyr wasn't complaining about the "on" argument, probably because it can be considered as part of the `...` "Other parameters passed onto methods.".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to be heavy-handed, you can do

```
aa = suppressMessages(inner_join(a, b))
```

The better choice, as Jazzurro suggests, is to specify the `by` argument. `dplyr` only prints a message to let you know what its guess is for which columns to join by. If you don't make it guess, it doesn't confirm things with you. This is a safer choice as well, from defensive coding standpoint.

If this is in a `knitr` document, you can set the chunk option `message=FALSE`.

Comment: Answer accepted - the suppressMessages was useful. I was hoping for a option switch that would turn off the message. But there is none. I should have checked the code of `dplyr`: there is a `message("Joining by: ", capture.output(dput(by)))` with no previous ifs. Just a comment, `dplyr` does not make a "guess is for which columns to join by", according to the documentation it selects the columns with the same name in both data-frames - there was no guess and IMHO there should be no message...

Comment: I would say it is "guessing" that you want to match on columns with the same name. Perhaps "assumption" would be a better descriptor than "guess". But anyone with much SQL experience will tell you that's not always what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, for me, the only time the messages are a problem is when I am using `dplyr::XX_join` in a function.  I don't necessarily want my functions to print warnings all the time.  However, when passing tables to a function to be joined (see comment by @kputschko) the column names of the tables will vary, so you can't hard-wire the `by` clause to prevent the message.

Suppressing all messages (e.g., with `suppressMessages()`) runs the risk of having no warning at all for unexpected behavior.

To suppress only the expected `Joining with by = join_by(a, b)` message without risking suppression of important messages, you can calculate a dynamic `by` parameter simply by determining the common column names between table `x` and table `y` (e.g., using `names(x)[names(x) %in% names(y)]`).

Some sample data for

```
t1 <- tibble::tibble(
    idx = letters[1:10],
    a = sample(1:3, 10, replace = T),
    b = sample(1:2, 10, replace = T)
  )

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   idx       a     b
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 a         1     1
 2 b         2     1
 3 c         3     2
 4 d         1     1
 5 e         2     2
 6 f         3     1
 7 g         1     2
 8 h         3     1
 9 i         2     1
10 j         2     1

t2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  1,  1, "Snap",
  1,  2, "Crackle",
  2,  1, "Pop",
  2,  2, "Bing"
)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
      a     b c      
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1     1 Snap   
2     1     2 Crackle
3     2     1 Pop    
4     2     2 Bing
```

Example of dynamic `by` with `inner_join()`:

```
> dplyr::inner_join(t1, t2, by = names(t1)[names(t1) %in% names(t2)])

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  idx       a     b c      
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 a         1     1 Snap   
2 b         2     1 Pop    
3 d         1     1 Snap   
4 e         2     2 Bing   
5 g         1     2 Crackle
6 i         2     1 Pop    
7 j         2     1 Pop
```

If you always want a quiet join, you could build a more flexible function that quiets any `xx_join` function you send it, like this:

```
quiet_join <- function(x, y, by = NULL, ..., join_fun = dplyr::inner_join){
  if(is.null(by)) by = names(x)[names(x) %in% names(y)]
  join_fun(x, y, by = by, ...)
}
```

Then just pass in the join function you want (if other than the default `inner_join`:

```
> quiet_join(x, y, join_fun = dplyr::left_join)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   idx       a     b c      
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
 1 a         3     1 NA     
 2 b         3     1 NA     
 3 c         1     2 Crackle
 4 d         1     2 Crackle
 5 e         1     1 Snap   
 6 f         3     1 NA     
 7 g         1     2 Crackle
 8 h         3     1 NA     
 9 i         1     2 Crackle
10 j         3     2 NA
```