# How to hide the text with the [warning message] color

Tags: r, warnings, r-markdown

When I use `lapply`, I generate a list with 52 dataframes. However there are also message `"Joining by: rowname (rowname exist in each 52 dataframes as a column)"`,and warning message.

[image]

I tried all different ways to hide the warning message and I succeed. Either change `rMarkdown` code or use `suppressWarning` in rfile works.

However, I have no idea about how to hide the `"Joining by"` message. 
I don't know which type of message this is (definitely not warning, but has the same color of warning message).

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to say what is producing these messages. My guess would be that the message is not produced by `warning()`, but possibly `print`. If that's the case, you can use `sink` to capture any printing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dplyr's joins in your EachTrip function I suggest checking the answers given in the SO question below to suppress join messages:

[How to make join operations in dplyr silent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311293/how-to-make-join-operations-in-dplyr-silent)